# Multiple errors with Java applet on client site

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, applet

We have a secured server (RSL) where my applet gets some errors (it worked well on other, less restrictive servers). I found java security signing so complicated; from version to version, from PC to PC etc. In one word, after researching for almost a week+ I came to a point where I cant seam I can move forward anymore.
What this applet does is simply uploads a local file to application FTP site. My users hate default INPUT control to browse a file, location of which is defined so, I made this applet simply to upload that defined file to this FTP site (this original project was done w/ classic asp some years ago; this is an upgrade per client request).
This java project uses apache FTPClient library and my package includes *commons-net-3.3.jar* (also few dependencies: *ant-apache-oro.jar*, *ant-commons-net.jar* and *jakarta-oro-2.0.8.jar*). There is absolutely no issue when I run this applet on my PC (eclipse). However problems start when I run the applet on production site (on that restrictive server). Here is how I sign and compile my jar.

START

**My *MANIFEST.MF* file content:**

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: commons-net-3.3.jar
Permissions: all-permissions
Trusted-Library: true
Created-By: 1.8.0_31 (company)
```

**My *.java.policy* file content:**

```
/* AUTOMATICALLY GENERATED ON Thu Feb 19 13:51:28 PST 2015*/
/* DO NOT EDIT */

keystore "JavaFileUploader.keystore";

grant {
  permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

**...and this is how I sign and compile my classes:**

```
keytool -genkey -alias JavaFileUploader -validity 1500 -keystore JavaFileUploader.ks
keytool -selfcert -keystore JavaFileUploader.ks -alias JavaFileUploader -validity 1500

javac JavaFileUploader.java
javac LinLyn.java
javac FTPUpload.java
jar cvfm JavaFileUploader.jar MANIFEST.MF *.class .java.policy JavaFileUploader.ks JavaFileUploader.txt

jarsigner -keystore JavaFileUploader.ks JavaFileUploader.jar JavaFileUploader
```

END

At the end I collect all my jar files (total of five: 4 already listed above and one-mine; *JavaFileUploader.jar*) and placed on the same directory where my asp pages are.

Right now this is what I'm getting from java console that bothers me and I think this is where all errors are hidden.

**A. When my applet appears - java console shows this suspicious messages (ips are changed):**

```
...
cache:  Read manifest for http://11.11.111.11/APPNAME/JavaFileUploader.jar: read=423 full=423
Missing Permissions manifest attribute in main jar: http://11.11.111.11/APPNAME/JavaFileUploader.jar
security: Missing Codebase manifest attribute for: http://11.11.111.11/APPNAME/JavaFileUploader.jar
security: Missing Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase manifest attribute for: http://11.11.111.11/APPNAME/JavaFileUploader.jar
...
```

**B. ...then, after I attempt to upload the file java console show this:**

```
...
network: Connecting http://11.11.111.11:21/crossdomain.xml with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://11.11.111.11:21/ with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://11.11.111.11:21/crossdomain.xml with cookie "ABCDEFGHIJKLMN=QRSTUVWXYZ; LAID=1"
java.io.IOException: Invalid Http response
...
```

**C. ...then few lines below, this:**

```
...
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "11.11.111.11:21" "connect,resolve")
...
```

1. I have no clue why java reports "*Missing Permissions manifest attribute in main jar*" in the first place when I have "*Permissions: all-permissions*" set on my MANIFEST.MF file. Same for other "missing" attributes...(section **A**)
2. On my second section of errors (section **B**) I'm guessing that *crossdomain.xml* file not found. Otherwise I don't see anything that clould generate *IOException*. "*Invalid Http response*" is the further result from *IOException* error I guess.
3. On my third section of errors (section **C**) I have no clue whatsoever, because other errors above could drain and end up errors to complete irrelevant point.

Please let me know if you had this kind of problem and have a solution.
Thanks.

***Here is the full content of the java console right after the applet appears:***

```
Java Plug-in 11.45.2.15
Using JRE version 1.8.0_45-b15 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
User home directory = C:\Users\MY_USER_NAME
----------------------------------------------------
c:   clear console window
f:   finalize objects on finalization queue
g:   garbage collect
h:   display this help message
l:   dump classloader list
m:   print memory usage
o:   trigger logging
q:   hide console
r:   reload policy configuration
s:   dump system and deployment properties
t:   dump thread list
v:   dump thread stack
x:   clear classloader cache
0-5: set trace level to <n>
----------------------------------------------------
basic: Added progress listener: sun.plugin.util.ProgressMonitorAdapter@1b1e125
security: Expected Main URL: http://11.11.111.11/APPNAME/JavaFileUploader.jar
basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.addURL parent called for http://11.11.111.11/APPNAME/JavaFileUploader.jar
Missing Permissions manifest attribute in main jar: http://11.11.111.11/APPNAME/JavaFileUploader.jar
security: Missing Codebase manifest attribute for: http://11.11.111.11/APPNAME/JavaFileUploader.jar
security: Missing Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase manifest attribute for: http://11.11.111.11/APPNAME/JavaFileUploader.jar
security: Validate the certificate chain using CertPath API
security: SSV validation:
    running: 1.8.0_45
    requested: null
    range: null
    javaVersionParam: null
    Rule Set version: null
network: Created version ID: 1.8.0.45
network: Created version ID: 1.8.0.45
security: continue with running version
network: Created version ID: 1.8.0.45
network: Created version ID: 1.8
network: Created version ID: 8.0.45
security: Missing Codebase manifest attribute for:
http://11.11.111.11/APPNAME/JavaFileUploader.jar
security: Missing Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase manifest attribute for: http://11.11.111.11/APPNAME/JavaFileUploader.jar
security: Validate the certificate chain using CertPath API
basic: Applet loaded.
basic: Applet resized and added to parent container
basic: PERF: AppletExecutionRunnable - applet.init() BEGIN ; jvmLaunch dt 549750 us, pluginInit dt 7116411154 us, TotalTime: 7116960904 us
basic: Applet initialized
basic: Starting applet
basic: completed perf rollup
basic: Applet made visible
basic: Applet started
basic: Told clients applet is started
```

***Here are addition messages on java console right after I apply my upload method:***

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "11.11.111.11:21" "connect,resolve")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.SecurityManagerHelper.checkConnectHelper(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.AWTAppletSecurityManager.checkConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:182)
    at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:203)
    at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:296)
    at FTPUpload.<init>(FTPUpload.java:21)
    at JavaFileUploader.uploadWithFlexibleConnection(JavaFileUploader.java:311)
    at JavaFileUploader.saveFileContent(JavaFileUploader.java:339)
    at JavaFileUploader.actionPerformed(JavaFileUploader.java:531)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

---

***OK. One error is gone. I've created an xml file, called 'crossdomain.xml' with following content:`***

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<cross-domain-policy>
  <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="master-only"/>
  <allow-access-from domain="*"/>
  <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Error described on section **B** is gone.
Posted full content of java console messages are the most recent error messages. You can see my "suspected errors;" described as **A** (line 4 on the 1st part) and **C** (very 1st line in the 2nd part).

Comment: **"My .java.policy file content:"**  Since that file is not installed on the client computer, it will have no effect and is therefore irrelevant.

Comment: Andrew, my .java.policy is included/packed with my jar file. Is this not enough?

Comment: LOL!  If getting around the security was *that* simple every virus and malware maker this side of ***..anywhere*** would have exploited that security hole long ago.  To gain trust, code must be **digitally signed.**  Forget all that crap about policy files, they are only of (limited) help during development.

Answer (score 0):

1. It's a good practice to sign all the .JARs (depedencies as well)
2. Try to include all the information below in your manifest:

```html
<codebase>http://location.of.your.jar/</codebase>
<permissions>all-permissions</permissions>
<Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase>http://location.of.your.jar/</Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase>
<Manifest-Version>1.0</Manifest-Version>
<Implementation-Title>App Name</Implementation-Title>
<Implementation-Version>0.1.0</Implementation-Version>
<Application-Name></Application-Name>
<Created-By>1.8.0_45</Created-By>
<Main-Class>package.YourClass</Main-Class>
<mode>development (or production)</mode>
<url>url of the application</url>
```

Sorry to answer this as an 'answer' but I can't put comments. I'm currently working on an applet and this approach has worked fine.

Comment: My manifest format is not an xml format (as you can see). Does it matter? Did you intentionally post the content of manifest file in xml format or that was how stockoverflow has formatted the page?

Comment: @SamSaarian No, it's in XML format because I generate it by Maven POM.XML in my project. You can write these tags in the way you prefer, but it's good to have them all in the manifest.